# Why JavaScript Object's property is already configurable:false, writable can always be changed from true to false without error?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

When I read YDKJS book in there say:

> There's a nuanced exception to be aware of: even if the property is already configurable:false, writable can always be changed from true to false without error, but not back to true if already false.

```
"use strict";
const obj = Object.create(null);
Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
   value: "Murad",
   writable: true,
   configurable: false,
   enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
   value: "Tofiq",
   writable: false,
   configurable: false,
   enumerable: true
});
```

But this is so interesting for me why JS have exception for writable?

Comment: As a guess, because tightening up security is not unsafe. Making a property read-only can not elevate access.

Comment: But this is so interesting for me this process bug or there are do it deliberately

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you're just asking about decisions made when creating the specification, you won't get a canonical answer here unless one of the authors makes an appearance.

Comment: There may be a documented reason somewhere.

Comment: This is so weird. If one property is not configurable but you can configure this. And many JS developers not interest this parts.

Comment: Why would it be a bug? Also, how would it be a bug, if it behaves the same way in multiple JS engines?

Comment: for example typeof null is bug and behaves same way multiple js engines :d

Comment: `typeof null` being `"object"` is not a bug either, just a bad decision. V8, SpiderMonkey and all the others intentionally code it the way it is, due to historical precedent.

Comment: https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html You can see typeof null absolutly bug and BrendanEich also say this is bug in comment.

Comment: This is interesting for me my question also happened for due to historical precedent or not

Comment: Again, `typeof null` being `"object"` _was_ a bug in the first version of JavaScript, which had to be finished in 10 days. A bug would have been fixed, as that's what you do with bugs you know of. Instead, it is a [misfeature](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/misfeature.html) due to JavaScript wanting to preserve backward compatibility, now a part of [JS spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator). The writable thing is also [in spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor), see step 7 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's by design

It is deliberately designed in the Language and implemented in v8

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property)

#### Modifying a property

When the property already exists, Object.defineProperty() attempts to modify the property according to the values in the descriptor and the object's current configuration. If the old descriptor had its configurable attribute set to false the property is said to be “non-configurable”. It is not possible to change any attribute of a non-configurable accessor property. For data properties, it is possible to modify the value if the property is writable, and it is possible to change writable attribute from true to false. It is not possible to switch between data and accessor property types when the property is non-configurable.

A TypeError is thrown when attempts are made to change non-configurable property attributes (except value and writable, if permitted) unless the current and new values are the same.

## Writable attribute

When the writable property attribute is set to false, the property is said to be “non-writable”. It cannot be reassigned.

But the error is thrown only in `strict` mode to enforce immutable types

Comment: Yeah I understand this is deliberately designed in the Language. But when there are make this this is interesting for me which situation there are saw and made it like today.